# php ошибка при генерации изображения формата webp, Fatal error: gd-webp encoding failed

Tags: php, webp

Пытаюсь сгенерировать из jpg картинки ее копию в webp.
Пример кода:

```
$file = 'img.jpg';
$im = imageCreateFromJpeg($file);
$pathInfo = pathinfo($file);
$res = imagewebp($im, $pathInfo['dirname'] . '/' . $pathInfo['filename'] . '.webp', 100);
```

Но в результате получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: gd-webp encoding failed
```

Такое происходит не со всеми картинками, а только с некоторыми. Буду благодарен любым рекомендациям. Проблемное изображение прикрепляю. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно решение на этот вопрос найдете [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078090/imagewebp-php-creates-corrupted-webp-files)

Comment: видел этот вопрос, там речь про некорректную генерацию изображения, в моем же случае падает непосредственно на вызове функции imagewebp